# Is it possible with one push to update two separate repositories?

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

As the question states in the title.

A little background: 
Our company is outsourcing, but we want the outsourcing guys to have the latest code and using best practices (like source control). Now we are also doing in house development. For confidentiality reasons we don't want to give them access to our in house source control but we will be collaborating on some projects.

Is there a way so that when I push from our end that I can update both our in house git set up and the outsourcer's git repository at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Use a hook in your in-house repository which triggers the (saved credentials) push to the remote repo.

Another way would be to just run a batch synchronization script from time to time.

A third, probably less effective way would be to make `git commit` locally be hooked to commit to both repos. I don't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually done this before.  My .git/config file looked like this:

```
[remote "github"]
    url = git@github.com:mattborn/raplets.git
    push = +:
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "personal"]
    url = ssh://mtborn@mattborn.net/~/raplets.git
    push = +:
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/mirror/*
[remote "origin"]
    # Push as equally authoritative
    url = git@github.com:mattborn/raplets.git
    url = ssh://mtborn@mattborn.net/~/raplets.git
    push = +:
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I don't think that this is necessarily a good idea... but I've done it.

Comment: I tried this as well but I'm not that fond of it. Sure, it works, but you still have to add the additional remote to all of your local repos. In my case I used this for a component being used (and developed on) in several projects. So instead of just running `git-clone` I'd also have to go through the `git-remote` setup each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use codebasehq you can setup a mirror repository that will update the other repository when you update the original one. Or, as Borealid said on his answer, you can setup a periodic task that synchronizes both repositories.